# Transform an object array to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

so here's the deal:

I have this array:

```
var g = {"e":[[1458642397809,104],[1458642467849,104],[1458642537847,107],[1458642607815,107]]};
```

I want to use this data to make a graph with highcharts, so here's my code:

```
$(function() {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        zoomType:'x',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'title'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: 'y',
        min: '0'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: 'Date',
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150,
        maxZoom: 20 * 1000
    },
    series: [{
      name:"title",
      data: [[1458642397809,104]
    }]
  });
});
```

the thing is, i need to transform my array

```
{"e":[[1458642397809,104],[1458642467849,104],[1458642537847,107],[1458642607815,107]]};
```

into this

```
[[1458642397809,104],[1458642467849,104],[1458642537847,107],[1458642607815,107]]
```

i tried multiple things but none of them seems to work, so I would love to have your help

Comment: `var newArr = g.e` ?

Comment: Oh my god guys, I am so embarrassed right now. Sorry to have asked such a silly quesition :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newArray = g.e; // [[1458642397809,104],[1458642467849,104],[1458642537847,107],[1458642607815,107]]
```

it will even contain the same reference, have i understood you correctly ?

Comment: Yeah, i'm quite tired and relatively new with js, sorry for my silly question! :x